# Android Studio constraint widget top and bottom margin doesn't respond

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to edit the margin using the constraint widget but top and bottom is not responding, why is [this](https://streamable.com/d4egvn) happening? It won't work like left and right margin.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issue. I am going to guess it is a bug, but you can code the margin as a workaround. Open the code for activity_main.xml, navigate to the view you want to give a margin, and add your desired margin (I added a left and top margin):

```
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
```

I think I am just going to try and get used to applying margins this way so that I am not limited by potential GUI bugs.

If this is not a bug, I'd love to know the reason why this happens.